# Why does trihaloacetaldehyde formed during the haloform reaction not undergo a Cannizzaro reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

We know trihaloacetaldehyde is formed during the haloform reaction of acetaldehyde with a halogen in strong base. Since it has no alpha hydrogens, I expected that it might undergo a Cannizzaro reaction, as we are using a strong base.   Why not?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haloform_reaction is for ketones not aldehydes.

Comment: @Mithoron Please go through the same link, you will find: The only primary alcohol and aldehyde to undergo this reaction are ethanol and ethanal,

Comment: Och, didn't thought about them in this context... Well then it happens for the same reason all haloform reactions happen: CX3 anion is leaving group good enough to be substituted by OH-. Much better then H- for that matter.

Answer (score 7):

Albeit haloform reaction is primarily for methyloketons, aldehydes which have relatively good leaving groups connected with carbonyl (like [chloral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloral)), or get it during halogenation, indeed also react.

Here we have another factor limiting usage of [Cannizzaro reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannizzaro_reaction), as although intermediate tetrahedral anion (6) could in principle undergo this reaction if $\ce{R = H-}$, it doesn't if there's a better leaving group then $\ce{H-}$. The point of haloform reactions is to make them if they aren't present already.

[image: mechanism]

([source of picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Haloform_Schritt_2.svg))