# Does it undergo Chloroform reaction or Canizzaro reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What are the products formed when **Trichloroacetaldehyde** is made to react with **NaOH**? I see 2 possible routes the reaction can take:

1. It can form **chloroform** and **Sodium formate**, since this is the final stage of the chloroform reaction
2. It can undergo Canizzaro reaction to give **Trichloroethanol** along with the sodium salt of **Trichloroacetic acid**.

Please tell me which reaction occurs and why.

Comment: Probably both...

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50469/isnt-the-reaction-of-chloral-with-sodium-hydroxide-a-disproportionation-reactio

Comment: Well that gets interesting https://books.google.pl/books?id=YyoUNYgBYJoC&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=chloral+cannizzaro+reaction&source=bl&ots=OUBbAA7vAr&sig=MXtYb4RM_6Hz4d2x2iJD_oFlKBQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uJUFVe_cGMjsgwSExYDgDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=chloral%20cannizzaro%20reaction&f=false says it undergoes both!